# Send the data as-is to the audio device in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: audio, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, pcm, audio-device

I have a custom Audio DAC device. I can connect it with Android/iOS smartphone by OTG cable. The main question is how to supply byte stream audio to the my device?
In UWP application I'm using [NAdio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) which provides wrapper for [WASAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455(v=vs.85).aspx) with exclusive mode access. I don't need to resample my generated data in bytes or mix them with system sounds and sounds from other apps.

Is it possible to reach my goal for mobile devices?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't need to resample my generated data in bytes or mix them with system sounds and sounds from other apps.
>
> Is it possible to reach my goal for mobile devices?

If your goal is to send audio data to your DAC device without resample and mix. The answer is no for android. I don't know if there is any third party library for automatically convert your audio data. But officially, you need to use native lib like [AAudio](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/aaudio/aaudio.html)  to conduct your audio data. You can also refer to [Best Practices for Android Audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0BPXZIvG-Q).

Comment: Referring to the AAudio documentation, I noticed the following: "AAudio might perform sample conversion on its own." But this is exactly what I want to avoid..